# Adding a MouseListener or MouseMotionListener to my JLabel that is inside of a Jpanel in my checkers-like board

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, mouseevent, jlabel

I'm really not sure what to do. I had started by making a new class that implements both MouseMotionListener and MouseListener and that takes in its constructor the JLabel:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class motion implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener {

    motion(JLabel im) {
        label1 = im;
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == label1) {
            drag = true;
        } 
    } 

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        drag = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        if (drag == true) {
            mouseX = e.getX();
            mouseY = e.getY();
            label1.setBounds(mouseX, mouseY, 
                    label1.getWidth(), label1.getHeight());
        }
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}  
    private JLabel label1;
    private int mouseX;
    private int mouseY;
    private boolean drag = false;

}
```

This is the code for my board. Currently the pieces aren't able to move. I had a line in each if statement to add a MouseMotionListener--picLabel.addMouseMotionListener(new motion(picLabel))--but that didn't work.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

   public class Checkerboard {
       public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException {
         JFrame checkerBoard = new JFrame();
         checkerBoard.setSize(700,700);
         checkerBoard.setTitle("Lines of Action");
         checkerBoard.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         int row = 8;
         int col = 8;
         Container pane = checkerBoard.getContentPane();
         pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(row,col));
         Color checker;   
         for (int x = 1; x <= (row * col); x++) {
            int altr = 0;
            altr = (x-1) % col;
            altr += (x-1) / col;

            if (altr % 2 == 0) {
               checker = Color.darkGray;
            } else {
               checker = Color.lightGray;
            }

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400/row, 400/col));
            panel.setBackground(checker);
            if ((x < 8 && x > 1) || (x < 64 && x > 57)) {
                BufferedImage myPicture = 
            ImageIO.read(new  File("C:\\Users\\srjames90\\Downloads\\BlackPiece.png"));
                JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon( myPicture ));
                picLabel.addMouseMotionListener(new motion(picLabel));
                panel.add(picLabel);
            } else if(check(x)) {
                BufferedImage myPicture = 
            ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\srjames90\\Downloads\\WhitePiece.png"));
                JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon( myPicture ));
                panel.add(picLabel);
            }
            pane.add(panel);
         }
         checkerBoard.setVisible(true);
      }

      static boolean check(int y) {
           return y == 9 || y == 16 || y == 17 || y == 24 || y == 25
                   || y == 32 || y == 33 || y == 40 || y == 41 || y == 48
                       || y == 49 || y == 56;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this add listener to the Motion class `JLabel`

```
Motion(JLabel im) {
    label1 = im;
    label1.addMouseListener(this);
}
```

Also please read [Java Programming Style Guidelines](http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html#General)

Answer (score 1):

`MouseListener` and `MouseMotionListener` define two different sets of events.  In order for your listener to get both sets, you have to register for both...using something like this:

```
Motion m = new Motion(picLabel);
picLabel.addMouseMotionListener(m); //will cause m to get mouseMoved and mouseDragged calls
picLabel.addMouseListener(m); //will cause m to get mousePressed, mouseReleased, mouseEntered, mouseExited, etc.
```

It's also worth noting that in the code snippet you posted, you're not adding any listener at all to your `WhitePiece.png` pieces.

Comment: this works, but now I can't move my chip across the board to another panel. It could only move around within the panel it was placed in. If I try to move a chip from its panel to another, it looks like the chip goes under the other panel.

Comment: That's correct - a GridLayout constrains the items you add to it to individual cells.    If you want to be able to drag-and-drop images around over top of your grid, you'll have to use a more complicated solution.  Swing has a built-in drag and drop framework, but it can be complicated to use; your other good option would be to try something involving a layer that sits over your GridLayout that handles dragging.